# Use SoundCloud's search page without a query

Tags: search, soundcloud

I'm using SoundCloud to download music that can be played in a commercial setting. For that, I'm searching with the filter license=to_use_commercially (and also duration=medium). I don't have any particular songs in mind; I'm basically just browsing.

I can't use Explore, because that doesn't have the necessary filters. I tried searching with a tag (e.g., "#piano"), but that seems to just be searching titles.

Is it possible to search SoundCloud with just filters, no query?

Comment: You can search with just a single letter of the alphabet. This seems like a bad idea though, because the results look like remixes of almost certainly copyrighted songs.